# Aurduino Mega prototype board connectors

Tags: arduino-mega

Might someone shed some light on the 52 pin connectors on the end of the prototype board? Both boards have no 52 pin female connectors, the board that doesn't include the breadboard wire has a male connector that is not 52 pins. The female connectors are hard to find. I've only looked on Ebay.

Thanks

[image: no 52 pin connectors[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRCjV.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I presume the pictured board has pins underneath (like an Arduino shield). It would be designed so you can stack more than one on top of each other.

Comment: Yes, the board is stackable. Not bad for 4.99.